# C++ - confused about declaring enums

Tags: c++, enums

So I am following a C++ tutorial on tutorialspoint.

I am really confused why the declaration of a new variable c is on the same line of declaring a new enum (kind of looks like a typedef thing to me):

```
 enum color { red, green, blue } c;
 c = blue;
```

If we want to make a new variable of type color, I cannot write

```
enum color {red,green,blue} newVar;
```

correct? In C++ is it enum color or just color?

Comment: Just say `color newVar;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment `color` is declared, you are allowed to add one or more variables at the end to declare them as type `color`, but this is the only place you can do this.  Thus, you can write:

```
enum color { red, green, blue } c;
color d;
```

or:

```
enum color { red, green, blue };
color c, d;
```

but not:

```
enum color { red, green, blue } c;
enum color { red, green, blue } d;
```

and also not:

```
enum color { red, green, blue };
enum color { red, green, blue } c;
```

As to your last question, the name of the type is just `color`, but in order to maintain backwards-compatibility with C, referring to it as `enum color` (e.g., `enum color d;`) is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

`color` is its own type, so you can do:

```
color street_light = red;
if(street_light == blue) {
    std::cout << "Bad light!" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes and enumerations allow to declare simultaneously the type and objects of the type. For example

```
enum color { RED, GREEN, BLUE} c = RED;
```

or

```
struct A { int x; int y; } a = { 10, 20 };
```

You even may use the same name for an object as the name of the type. For example

```
enum color { RED, GREEN, BLUE} color = RED;
```

or

```
struct A { int x; int y; } A = { 10, 20 };
```

In this case the name of the object hides the name of the type.

If you want to define another object of the type you have to use elaborated name. For example

```
enum color { RED, GREEN, BLUE} color = RED;
struct A { int x; int y; } A = { 10, 20 };
enum color c = GREEN;
struct A a;
```

You may not write simply

```
color c = GREEN;
A a;
```

because the names of the types were hidden by the names of the objects.